# sending packets to a tap interface using python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tap, openvpn

I've been trying to send packets to a tap interface using python. I'm monitoring the tap interface using wireshark and no packets are being received. I'm doing this as an exercise mainly to help my understanding of vpns, ethernet bridging and socket programming in python.

My System Setup is as follows:

```
Ubuntu Desktop 11.10
Python 2.7
eth0 ip: 192.168.1.6
tap0 ip: 10.0.0.1
```

I first setup the tap as follows:

```
sudo openvpn --mktun --dev tap0
sudo ifconfig tap0 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.0.255 promisc up
```

This starts the tap0 interface and creates a kernel routing rule to 10.0.0.1/24 via tap0.

Here is the route table:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0
192.168.1.6     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Next I start python interactive and create a simple UDP socket.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto('helloworld',('10.0.0.2',12345))
```

I run the sendto command with Wireshark monitoring on tap0. Now, there is no host at 10.0.0.2 on my network, but I should at least see some outgoing traffic on the tap0 interface. I have replicated this in windows and it seems to work ok.

I can only think that the problem lies somewhere in the setup of the tap0 interface under linux. That or my mediocre understand of this stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked your routing table? What is the output of the command `ip route`?

Comment: i've added the route table. As you can see, traffic on 10.0.0.1/24 should go out over the tap0 interface.

Comment: As this actually is *not* python related, but networking, it should probably be on superuser instead of SO.

Comment: ok i've posted to superuser. Should this post be marked as answered or closed or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an ethertap interface, you probably will actually *not* see outgoing traffic, if the ARP cache still has the negative (incomplete) entry. Otherwise, you probably seen an ARP packet only.

I don't think this is related to python, actually.

Did you try a ping - do you see an icmp packet go out? What does the arp table look like?

Comment: Yes, the ARP packets are exactly what I expected to see. I have just tried this exact same experiment at work on a Fedora15 box. It works. ARP packets are sent on the interface.

Any idea if this could be a ubuntu or later linux kernel issue?

Comment: Well, what is in your ARP table? You don't want to send unnecessary ARP requests, if you still have some cached.

Comment: arp -i tap0 returns Address: 10.0.0.2 HWaddress:(incomplete) Iface:tap0

I tried a ping, there was only an ARP broadcast, no IP packets.

Comment: So it must have sent an ARP request some time ago. Probably before you started wiretap. Yes, ping will also not send ICMP packets, if there was no ARP *reply*. Because there is no one to send it to.

Comment: I am monitoring tap0 in real time with wireshark. The moment I ping 10.0.0.2 an ARP broadcast is sent on the tap0 interface. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. One thing that is certain though is that I am getting different behaviour between to two different machines I am trying this on.

Comment: Yes. This is the expected behavior. Consider reading up on ARP, to understand why the packets are not sent without an ARP *reply* to the broadcast.